# How to properly set content caching for a .Net application running in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, pagespeed, http-caching

In my MVC3 project I have the following class-level attributes set on some of my controllers:

```
 [OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration = 14400, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

Duration = four hours.

I used `VaryByParam = "*"` as there are differing parameters for the controller's action methods, instead of  `VaryByParam = "none"` - Is this the correct use?

In IIS, on the server level and in all the web.config files for my sites, I set the static caching to eight days.

Observing the headers in Fiddler, when I go to a search result page, I see the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2013 17:21:32 GMT
Content-Length: 148842
```

For my site scripts js files:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=691200
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Last-Modified: Thu, 15 Aug 2013 05:35:35 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "10906a447999ce1:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2013 17:21:32 GMT
Content-Length: 2999
```

And for css:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=691200
Last-Modified: Wed, 07 Aug 2013 21:31:28 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "f08ce079b593ce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2013 17:21:33 GMT
```

Using Google's PageSpeed affiliate (http://www.webpagetest.org/) I was able to get up to around 90/100 on my pages - page load time is about 4 seconds, the report shows .47s optimized - see the confusing results [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51899/exactly-what-is-googles-pagespeed-service-recommending-and-how-to-optimize-css) .  When I playback the video on WebPageTest of Original vs. Optimized, my original finishes in 2.5s (and has a lower speed index) and optimized in 4.7s.

Google's PageSpeed Insights suggests to optimize CSS delivery.  I am already serving up CSS asynchronously.

As I am hosting on AWS, I cranked up the juice on the instance to one of their most powerful server instances.  Page load times were about the same as my regular instance.

So I am confused by the first result up top: Cache-Control: no-cache .  Have I not implemented caching correctly, and if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I would recommend you do not divulge information about your server ("Server", "X-Powered-By") on each response. It's a bit of a security issue (http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/02/shhh-dont-let-your-response-headers.html) and you are adding a couple of bytes to EACH response for no reason.

Comment: Vary: * means "I cannot possibly represent the factors that led to the selection of this response using headers alone, so hit the server on every request."

Comment: Updating my class-level caching to "Any", as I only care about a refresh every 4 hours or so... [OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Any, Duration = 14400, VaryByParam = "None")]

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta - Thanks for the clean-up tips.  Got the headers all clean now through the Global.asax.